# How to easily start a fire in a charcoal for grilling without using gas?

Tags: food

Are there any life hacks for starting a fire in a pack of charcoal for grilling without using gas? I do have access to matches, lighters, etc.

Comment: hm... would a fire piston work？

Comment: This is the best way to light charcoal https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoRGGLahuVU&t=3s

Answer (score 12):

I really like to use the *"chimney starter"* that came with my Weber Kettle for this. I really don't want to advertise for Weber but those things are good! You may find something comparable or can build one yourself.

Instead of just placing the charcoals in your grill, place your *chimney starter* in the grill and fill that with charcoals. Then just stuff some ring shaped newspaper underneath it, make sure air supply is ensured and light it.

Your charcoal is ready whey you see  orange color deep inside the chimney starter. Make sure to wear heat-resistant gloves and pour the charcoals into your grill.

The below image uses paraffin cubes instead of newspaper. You can basically use any kind of firelighters, but you'll usually already have some newspaper laying around.

[image]

---

**Text- & image-source:**

[The Virtual Weber Bullet - How To Use A Chimney Starter](http://virtualweberbullet.com/chimney.html)

Comment: These things are excelent, and if you're careful/sensible then you don't need heat resistant gloves. They also work for small amounts of wood, or lumpwood charcoal as well as briquettes.

Comment: We have one of these, excellent thing. You could make one yourself from a big tin (paint or sauerkraut or so) with the top and bottom cut out, and holes punched for air. You'd have to invent a handle though, they get really hot. The hard part is where to put it once your grill is lit. We put it on a stone slab on the wooden deck. If fact the grill-expert used to light it on there too, and at the end of summer there was a big burn mark under the stone.

Comment: and has the added benefit of being ready faster than just a pile of charcoal.

Answer (score 4):

Toilet paper and cooking oil:

- Make 4-5 cones of toilet paper by wrapping it round 3 fingers about 6 times.
- Drizzle cooking oil into each cone, about a teaspoon in each (it can get messy, do this over the charcoal)
- Spread the cones evenly through the charcoal and sort of bury them in so the top of the cones are at the same level as the top of the bed, standing vertically.
- Place a few pieces of charcoal around the top edges of the cones, but not covering them completely.
- Carefully light each cone and watch it all take place

Make sure the cones are big enough and saturated enough that they don't burn out too quickly. You may need to shuffle the charcoal around a bit to make sure they are getting enough flames on them.

This method is as effective as using firelighters (and cheaper, and probably cleaner!).

Answer (score 3):

Paper and cooking oil. You can make a bed of scrunched up paper (newspaper is probably about the best) under the charcoal. Paper burns up quickly so you need a lot of it. You can drizzle cooking oil on the charcoal. Cooking oil won't set light easily but the burning paper will get it hot enough and give the flames enough intesity and longevity to get the coals smouldering. I'm assuming this is for a barbecue. When getting it started, you want it sheltered from the wind (but not smothered with a lid). Once the flames have died down, you want to get airflow to the coals, by moving it if safe.

Comment: Funny enough, I use a similar method, but put the cooking oil on the paper and not the charcoal. It prevents the paper from burning quickly and provides a secondary fuel for the paper to burn.

Answer (score 0):

I've used different techniques with more or less success :

- simple plain Zip barbecue starters (or similar) : not very efficient used alone
- zip + paper : slightly more efficient, not much, paper won't last long
- paper + kindling : like this method, but can be a bit slow and do a lot of smoke, you also need kindling...
- zip + kindling : a bit less smoke and ashes than previous method

basically, I love using kindling, but there are also other solutions like the one proposed by Alex. I've already seen it in action and indeed it was quite impressive. You don't need to go Weber for this, other brands have this kind of tool, the idea being to avoid charcoal to spread and concentrate it right above the fire. Air circulation is also very good. Some barbecue actually include this "chimney" under the barbecue self. But that's a tool more that you need...

Answer (score 0):

I used an electric coil BBQ starter. It's a heating element like you would find at the bottom of your dishwasher, but small with a handle and a cord. You stack the charcol briquetes in a pyrimid on top of it and plug it in. In a few minutes the coal will start with a small flame. Take the coil out so not to damage it and wha-la a fire with out gas, starter or oil.

Answer (score 0):

Get a old ice cube tray or two, I use six at a time. Get a old sauce pan, melt wax and pour. "Hint" Garage sales for old candles or buy some its cheap. Some people use old egg cartons and do away with standard charcoal use hard wood charcoal.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. I'm not sure I understand what your answer is trying to say. You mention ice cube trays, sauce pans, and egg cartons, but I'm not really sure what you're answer actually is. Could you clear this up?